# Android: wake up device using Alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wakelock

I'm using the follwing code for setting Alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(reminderContext, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
System.currentTimeMillis()+delay,pendingIntent);
```

When the alarm goes off, I executed same code that show a new Activity and a sound is reproduced. This is good, but if my device is in sleep mode, when the alarm goes off I can hear just the sound. No activity is shown and my device remains looked and in sleep mode.

What can I do in order to obtain an automatically wake up of my device when the alarm goes off?

EDIT:

I tried the following:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
wakeLock.acquire();

KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

That seemed to work with the exception of this:

```
04-10 13:49:59.260: A/PowerManager(4292): WakeLock finalized while still held: TAG
```

Moreover, I have this warning on acquire method:

> Found a wakelock acquire() but no release() calls anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i wake up my android when it is not plugged in and sleeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262641/can-i-wake-up-my-android-when-it-is-not-plugged-in-and-sleeping)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code in your `Receiver` Activity:

```
Window wind;
wind = this.getWindow();
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
wind.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to edit that after Android version 4.4, the `setRepeating` method has been deprecated and they have introduce [`setInexactRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Please go through this update blog for setting alarm:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html